# how to close the view controller that I open with "replace" segue

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I've unsuccessfully tried:

```
1. [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];



 2. [[self parentViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
    completion:Nil];



 3. //from the parent view controller using a delegate 
        -(void)closeReplaceController
        {
            DLog(@"closeReplaceController");
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];

        }
```

Comment: Didn't manage to do the expected behavior using the  "replace" segue. Eventually did it using the "push" segue with hidden navbar and "popViewController" method to close viewcontroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
-(void)killPresentingView
{
    UIViewController *vc = [self presentingViewController];
    [vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And see what happens. If I understood you right, this should work.

Comment: dismissModalViewControllerAnimated " Dismisses the view controller that was presented by the receiver. (Deprecated in iOS 6.0. Use dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: instead.)" --- it seems like in my case it will not have effect. In any case thanks.

Comment: @barn.gumbl Whoops, sorry about that. But have you tried dismissing the `presentingViewController` (using either `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` or otherwise)?